# Converting DATE columns in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following text file `aatest.txt`:

```
09/25/2019 | 1234.5
10/01/2018 | 6789.0
```

that would like to convert into `zztext.txt`:

```
2019-09-25 | 1234.5
2018-10-01 | 6789.0
```

My Postgres script is:

```
CREATE TABLE documents (tdate TEXT, val NUMERIC);
COPY documents FROM 'aatest.txt' WITH CSV DELIMITER '|';
SELECT TO_DATE(tdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy');
COPY documents  TO 'zztest.txt' WITH CSV DELIMITER '|';
```

However I am getting the following error message:
`ERROR:  column "tdate" does not exist`
What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SELECT has no FROM clause, so you can't reference any columns. But you need to put that SELECT into the COPY statement anyways:

```sql
CREATE TABLE documents (tdate TEXT, val NUMERIC);
COPY documents FROM 'aatest.txt' WITH CSV DELIMITER '|';
COPY (select to_char(TO_DATE(tdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-mm-dd'), val FROM documents) 
   TO 'zztest.txt' WITH CSV DELIMITER '|';
```